# A fair deal for purchasing a true story

Tags: non-fiction

My cousin is an extraordinary little girl from an extraordinary family. She was featured last Christmas on NBC Nightly News.

I have discussed with her about writing a book about their story because it needs to be told and people need to read about it. I write pretty well but don't have a publishing background and they don't have anyone seeking their story rights.

I was thinking about offering to write the book on spec optioning their rights on spec for something like 6 months and then we would each receive half of the profits of the book.

Does anyone have any experience writing books in this situation? Does this seem like a fair deal on both sides?

Answer (score 1):

A *fair deal on both sides* really depends on the sides. To me it seems fair. But to them it might not. So the best thing to do would be to discuss it with them. A person like your cousin or her parents (just an example here; nothing personal) might say that since this is the child's story, they might deserve more than half the profits. Or they might say that you should agree on a price beforehand and stick to that. There are many different options here and I doubt anyone can actually tell you what you should do, besides discussing it with your cousin (and her parents if she is underage).

Comment: I guess I'm looking for other deals people have made to see what they've done so I can put this on some kind of scale. I tried googling, but didn't seem to find much.

Comment: Did you discuss it with your cousin's family?

Comment: Not yet. It's on my list of things to do, but I wanted to try doing a little research first.